Why perforce doesn't support `@changelist` syntax for `share` mappings?
The documentation on stream paths states that @changelist syntax limits upper revisions of import'ed files by specific "depot revision" (called changelist), why it doesn't support the same for share'ed paths? It makes sense to also cap all other files by specific revision just not to make multiple different histories for different mapped paths
For example, I can do this:
import ... //my_stream/path/...@12345
share folder_a/...

That leads to project structure like that:
- folder_a (shared)
- folder_b (imported)
- folder_c (imported)

At that point we have a project, requiring two distinct steps to get the latest revision for:

Get latest action for import'ed files (which will always cap to the 12345 version of files of the project)
Merge down from parent stream, which requires not to forget to specify Up to 12345 in filters tab

The latter step makes it unclear because if you forget to specify Up to ... filter, it will lead to integrity issues (code and art out of historical sync, for example). Is it somehow possible to fix share changelist in the stream?
It makes no sense to have share'd files in future relative to import'ed part, why does it even exist as a feature in Perforce?

share is for branched paths that you will make local modifications to; it doesn't make sense to have a revision limit on files that you submit new changes to, since the new changes would logically be excluded by the limit.
If you never plan to modify files in a path and just want to inherit them from the parent stream, import is indeed the right path type to use!
The scenario you describe is one that won't actually happen in practice -- if you have already branched a path at @12345 and want to exclude later parent changes, you will simply never want to merge it, since no new changes will ever be submitted before that point.  Merging from @12345 will always be a no-op, so there's no reason to ever do it.
In that situation if you wanted to automatically exclude the path from merges while continuing to make local changes you'd use isolate.  (See this related question: How to properly manage file versions when using branch mapping merge in Perforce?)

I mean that share by changelist could limit only merge down action versions, not directly submitted. I think it makes sense that you want to make changes only on top of @12345  while your imported paths are also in sync with @12345. The code will become incompilable if you import some code at @12345 and get latest for another part of share'd code, it makes no sense to do so

Not necessarily -- the idea of stream "paths" is that each represents an entirely independent module that builds on its own.  You might want to import one module at version 1.4 and another at 3.7 depending on your project's needs.  What you're doing (based on what you've described in your recent questions) is atypical and maybe unnecessarily complex -- the easy thing would be to just have one share path!
